# How to count how many repetitive formulas are in a column of data frame? R

Tags: r

https://filebin.net/vbm8muzlcxuyvcrd

Hi, I have a data frame and I want to subset only the Protein.IDs that appear 3 times or more in the column AA$Protein.IDs
I was trying something like

```
AA %.% group_by(Protein.IDs) %.% summarise(n()))
```

it's giving me errors, and I cant quite figure out how to subset that,
help please help

Comment: `AA %>% group_by(Protein.IDs) %>% summarize(Count = n()) %>% filter(Count >= 3)` works fine for me. Try naming the column calculated by `n()`

Comment: Oh, I missed it the first time but `%.%` isn't a valid pipe, it must be `%>%`

Comment: There are a couple of other valid types of pipes (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/magrittr.pdf)) but `%.%` is not one.

Comment: It used to be `dplyr` 's pipe before they imported it from `magrittr`. A version update might have confused OP.

Comment: when i try the code              AA %>% group_by(Protein.IDs) %>% summarize(Count = n()) %>% filter(Count >= 3)                  it gives me error "Error: This function should not be called directly". I don't get it